# django custom save method issue with newly created object id

Tags: django, django-models

The following is one of my save methods in a model.

Im trying to use the newly created id when the object is saved to populate another field as seen in line 73. This doesn't work very well presumably because the object hasn't been created yet.

What's the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Where should I move the super method to?

```
 64     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 65         '''
 66         Save invoice and receipt number
 67         '''
 68         
 69         if self.status == 'pending' and self.invoice is None:
 71             invoice = "%s-Inv-%s-%s" % (self.event.event_acronym,
 72                                         date.today().strftime('%y%m%d'),
 73                                         self.id)
 74             self.invoice = invoice
 75             super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
 76 
 77         if self.status == 'completed' and self.receipt is None:
 78             total_success = Order.objects.all.filter(status='completed').count()
 79             if not total_success:
 80                 receipt = "%s-R-%s-%s" % (self.event.acronym,
 81                                           date.today().strftime('%y%m%d'),
 82                                           1)
 83             else:
 84                 receipt = "%s-R-%s-%s" % (self.event.event_acronym,
 85                                           date.today().strftime('%y%m%d'),
 86                                           total_success + 1)
 87             self.receipt = receipt
 88             self.receipt_date = datetime.datetime.now
 89             super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use signals instead of overwrite the method save in the object:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

If you call the method save in the method save, line 75, you can have problems of recurrence, maybe you need figure out what code execute in pre_save signal (the object her3 may not have id) and what in post_save (here have id always)

Answer (score 0):

if you want access to the saved object, you need to run super().save() first
so e.g. move line 75 in the above to before line 71

though it may be worth taking a step back and thinking about what your are **actually** trying to achieve. as noted above, signals may be your friend here

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is self doesn't have an id until *after* its saved by the ORM.

```
if not self.id:
   # is True the first time an object is saved
```

A signal will let you fire a function after the object is saved, so it will have it's ID and you can go about your business.